# PHP cli script for flushing drupal cache

Tags: caching

So I have created script that flushes drupal's cache and it's ran in CLI.

The problem is after first use, I can't use the script again, because some classes ('SelectQueryExtender' or 'DrupalDefaultEntityController') are missing. Clearing cache via drupal admin menu (admin_menu/flush-cache) fixes it and I can rerun.

Now the question is why clearing cache from via HTTP works and from CLI doesn't?

I'm running on Drupal 7 and code can be found below:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/srv/www/'); // Drupal root folder.

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
// Clear cache.
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

EDIT: when I clear cache via drupal_flush_all_caches and later make curl call for cache clearing through apc-status.php, then even website itself gives Fatal on above mentioned classes missing.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, it won't run until you fix those

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case as DRUPAL_ROOT part was only line that was not copied.

Comment: why are you not using drush ?

Comment: I don't see a necessity of having one big tool for such a minor thing and also I would like, actually need to know the logic behind this behaviour.

Comment: Okey, apperantly I had script starting on wrong folder thus breaking modules search. Basically for drupal_flush_all_caches() to work (or registry_rebuild to be more percise), script would need to be at same place where DRUPAL_ROOT is located or chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT); should be used after drupal_bootstrap. 

Next time I will add more code as this wasn't informative enough.

Comment: @R.P If you'd be good enough to summarise what you did to make the fix in an answer that'd be great - this is a Q+A site after all :) Answering your own question is encouraged as it might help someone out with the same problem in the future, and comments are likely to be deleted without much notice

Answer (score 1):

Install Drush. It's your friend. Then you can issue

```
drush cc all
```

To clear caches.

You can also rebuild registries if needed to if you have that module installed.